# Is a combination of binomially distributed random variables also binomially distributed?

Tags: binomial-distribution, random-variable

Suppose I have random variable

X = C/(A*B)

where C, A, and B are all independent binomially (but not identically) distributed random variables whose parameters I know. Is X also binomially distributed? What are the parameter values?

Edit: Some clarification due to comments:

1) Suppose we only consider distribution of X for A*B!=0

2) X is non-integer so it is not binomially distributed...

Comment: Is X defined when A or B are 0?

Comment: A binomial random variable assumes integer values, x is real and then cannot be binomial distributed

Comment: Noah, suppose X is only defined when A and B are non-zero.

Comment: niandra82 -- that's a good point.

Comment: Your final line seems to be an answer to your own question. You could post it as an answer (or @niandra82 could).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it answers itself.

Answer (score 3):

A binomial random variable assumes integer values, x is real and then cannot be binomial distributed